# Direct3D 11 texture in ABGR format when RGBA requested

Tags: direct3d, hlsl, texture-mapping, direct3d11

I am trying to learn how to do texture mapping in Direct3D 11.

I have successfully mapped a texture onto a quad. The problem is that Direct3D is interpreting my pixel data as ABGR, when I specifically requested `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8`, and I don't understand why.

Here is the code I use to create my `ID3D11Texture2D` object:

```
UINT pixels[] = {
    0xff00ff00, 0xff0000ff,
    0xffff0000, 0xffffffff,
};

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresourceData;
subresourceData.pSysMem = pixels;
subresourceData.SysMemPitch = 8;
subresourceData.SysMemSlicePitch = 16;

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texture2dDesc;
texture2dDesc.Width = 2;
texture2dDesc.Height = 2;
texture2dDesc.MipLevels = 1;
texture2dDesc.ArraySize = 1;
texture2dDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
texture2dDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
texture2dDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
texture2dDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
texture2dDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
texture2dDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
texture2dDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

ID3D11Texture2D *texture;
device->CreateTexture2D(&texture2dDesc, &subresourceData, &texture);
```

The code for creating the `ID3D11ShaderResourceView` object:

```
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;
memset(&shaderResourceViewDesc, 0, sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

ID3D11ShaderResourceView *shaderResourceView;
device->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderResourceView);
```

The code for creating the `ID3D11SamplerState` object:

```
D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
memset(&samplerDesc, 0, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));
samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT;
samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;

ID3D11SamplerState *samplerState;
device->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &samplerState);
```

And finally the HLSL pixel shader:

```
Texture2D image;
SamplerState samplerState;

float4 PixelMain(float4 position: SV_POSITION, float2 texel: TEXCOORD): SV_TARGET {
    return image.Sample(samplerState, texel);
}
```

The colors of the rendered texture are

```
green  red
blue   white
```

But they should be

```
black  red
black  white
```

And, of course, I remembered to call `deviceContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &shaderResourceView);` and `deviceContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &samplerState);`

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue. Most processors you're likely to deal with store integers in "little-endian" order. Which means that an integral value of `0xAABBCCDD` ends up in memory as the four bytes `0xDD, 0xCC, 0xBB, 0xAA`, in that order. I know it's counter-intuitive, so I encourage you to use the Visual Studio memory window to view how your pixels array end up represented in memory.

Direct3D/your GPU does not consider a pixel as a 32-bit integer, but as four consecutive 8-bit integers, so it won't swap the bytes again when reading from the texture and will see an effective pixel value of `0xDDCCBBAA`. The solution is to specify your image in a byte array with four entries per pixel, one per component. In your case:

```
BYTE pixels[] = {
    0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff,
    0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
};
```

Also, the `SysMemSlicePitch` parameter is irrelevant for 2D textures. No need to set it to 16. And an alpha value of zero does not make your pixels black. You need to turn on and play with the blending states to achieve that.